# CSS Animate an object and retain its new position

Tags: css, web

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Animation</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            .container
                {
                    background-color: blue;
                    height: 200px;
                    width: 200px;
                    position: relative;
                    -webkit-animation-name:animate;
                    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;  
                }

                @-webkit-keyframes animate  
                {
                    0%
                    {
                    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
                    }

                    100% 
                    {
                    -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
                    }
                }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="container">
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The above code animates an object,but after the animation it returns to original position.How to retain it in the new position? which means the square must not return to (0,0)

Comment: Would it work for you to use a transition rather than an animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `animation-fill-mode` property.

> The animation-fill-mode property specifies a style for the element
>   when the animation is not playing (when it is finished, or when it has
>   a delay).
>
> By default, CSS animations do not affect the element until the first
>   keyframe is "played", and then stops once the last keyframe has
>   completed. The animation-fill-mode property can override this
>   behavior.
>
> -[CSS3 animation-fill-mode Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp)

**`-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards` make the movement permanent, once the animation has run its course.**

```css
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ashesh, BaTmaN's code is fine,but it depends on the value of property i'm using.

Comment: yes, that will work but requires more work (and LOCs).

Answer (score 1):

Now it will stay at the last frame. I have added the  `-webkit-transform: translate(100px,100px);` to the container class.

```
             .container
            {
                background-color: blue;
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
                position: relative;
                -webkit-animation-name:animate;
                -webkit-animation-duration:1s;  
              -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; 
                -webkit-transform: translate(100px,100px); 
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes animate  
            {
                0%
                {
                -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
                }

                100% 
                {
                -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
                }


            }
```

http://jsbin.com/nimuniviqa/2/

Comment: yeah it worked. After the animation,it translated it to (100,100) .Simple trick though :P Thanks